# Respect the stranger?

Tags: shemot-exodus, parshat-devarim, public-policy, ger-toshav, yetzias-mitzrayim

The word גר is commonly translated convert. However, we are commanded to love the גר as we were גרים  in Egypt. Exodus 22:21, ibid 23:9, Deuteronomy 10:18-19. How can the Jewish people be said to have converted to the Egyptian religion or way of life?

Comment: A literal definition of גר is 'stranger'. That's the definition used in that context.

Comment: Perhaps "foreigner" is a better translation (per that context) as explained by Rashi in the first citation.

Comment: Yes but can we really darshen the same word used in the same pasuk has two separate meanings ?

Comment: Who said it's a defined in two different manners in the same Pasuk? Why can't both instances of the word גר  in the Pasuk refer to strager/foreigner?

Comment: To elaborate on Salmononius2's point: The word may generically mean 'foreigner', and can therefore be used to describe a convert, who is a foreigner vis-a-vis the Jewish nation he is now joining

Answer (score 2):

See [רבינו בחיי](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/22.20#e1n6) who explains that the Hebrew word for a stranger, "גר," is derived from "גרגיר," which refers to an isolated berry at the far end of a solitary branch, illustrating a convert's isolation. The Torah reminds the Israelites to empathize with strangers since they themselves were mistreated as strangers in Egypt. G-d implies that, just as He showed mercy to them when they had no one else to turn to, He will do the same for converts if necessary. Notably, the Torah uses the phrase "וְאַתֶּם יְדַעְתֶּם אֶת נֶפֶש הַגֵּר," which means "you know the soul (feelings) of a stranger," emphasizing that strangers often struggle with low self-esteem and have no one to turn to except G-d, therefore G-d will look after them.